# Python sympy: Expressions with an undefined function whose value at zero is known

Tags: functions, substitution, python

I'm trying to evaluate an expression in sympy using a function $f(x)$. The function is unknown, but its value at $0$ is known $f(0)=0$. If it's any help, specifically I want to evaluate the Taylor series of f(x)'s inverse using Lagrange's Inversion Theorem.

This means I want to evaluate $$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \Big(\frac{x}{f(x)}\Big)^n \Big|_{x=0}$$

Obviously, L'Hopital's rule should be applied, and often, but using `subs(<expression>, x, 0)`, sympy discards all terms with a nominator with $x$ as equalling $0$, ignoring that the denominator, with $f(x)$ might be also $0$. The result is trivial and wrong.

What can I do for a right treatment of my question?

Comment: You can't evaluate the Taylor series by only knowing the value at a point. Left alone if in that point the function is not even defined.

Comment: I know all the derivatives at 0, which means I know the Taylor Series (at 0) for f(x). Lagrange's theorem gives me a formula for the inverse's Taylor Series coefficients. sympy could evaluate everything I need, if only it was aware that 0/0 != 0.

Comment: Maybe if you write down what the value of the derivatives are this can help. If all the derivative are zero than it is the zero function and $\frac{x}{f(x)}$ is ill defined. Btw if you know all the derivatives then the function is not unknown, you know it (in a neightbourhood of $0$)

Comment: @Marco Only if the Taylor series converges pointwise to the function which need not be the case.